# How to validate if body parameter in Express Nodejs string can be converted to JSON using express-validation and joi

Tags: node.js, validation, express, joi

I am creating a function that accepts a post request. The post request also contains a JSON object converted to a String. On the backend, I need to validate if this string can indeed be parsed into JSON and only then proceed. There is the routing function:

```
var express = require('express');
var validate = require('express-validator');

var hotelController = require('../controllers/hotel-controller');
var hotelValidation = require('../validations/hotel-validation');

var router = express.Router();


router.route('/create')
    .post(validate(hotelValidation.createHotel), 
hotelController.create);
```

Here is the validation object:

```
var Joi = require('joi');

module.exports = {
    createHotel: {
        body: {
            //NEED TO CHECK IF THE BELOW FIELD 
            //CAN BE CONVERTED TO JSON FROM STRING
            data: Joi.string().required()
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Not sure if i got your question correctly but won't `Joi.object()` do the job for you ?

Comment: `Joi.object()` would directly check if that variable were an object right? I need to convert the string to an object and then see..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented on the question, `Joi.object()` will still work with a `JSON` string, `Joi.array()` works too.

[It's documented in the API](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v10.4.1/API.md#object)

> Generates a schema object that matches an object data type (as well as JSON strings that parsed into objects).

For example, given the schema:

```
Joi.object().keys({
  body: Joi.object().keys({
    data: Joi.object(),
    array: Joi.array()
  })
})
```

A valid payload can be:

```
{
  body: {
    data: '{"json": true, "foo": "bar"}',
    array: '[1, 2, 3, "hello", 4, "world"]'
  }
}
```

The above example can be demoed [here](http://framp.me/joi-tester/), just paste the schema and example data in.